# I want to split string with only 2 space although the next string is space

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to split string with only 2 space and then i want to get next string   although the next string is space

`Ex. [red  blue  green     orange  yellow  ]`

and this is result that i want 
`[red,blue,green, ,orange,yellow, ]`

What i have to do?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: Another "give-me-regex" question

Comment: i try but the result like this  [red, blue, green,  ,  orange, yellow]. It have one space before orange

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    String str = "red  blue  green     orange  yellow  ";
    String[] result = arg.split("  ");

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
        System.out.println(result[i]+',');
```

This is the output:

> red,
>   blue,
>   green,
>   ,
>    orange,
>   yellow,

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to take the space of "orange", just do `str.split(" ");` and then take all its items (strings) bigger than 1, then you would be taking only the words ignoring the blank spaces, but you couldn't get the double space as a string.
Other way to reach what you want is to do what I said at first and then use `str[i].trim()` in the for loop, but again, you won't be able to take double space as string.

Anyway, you should give us more info and details about your question, like what did you tried before.